# Approximation of the golden ratio using exponential

Tags: inequality, power-series, exponential-function, approximation, golden-ratio

Claim :

$$\left(1+e^{-1}\right)^{3}\cdot\left(1-e^{-1}\right)-\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}{2}<0$$

---

---

I found it accidentaly using Desmos .It's quite good as approximation of the golden ratio.

Some thought :

I recall that :

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

And we can also use the [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)  to get a good approximation of $\phi$ using the $n$ th root .

---

---

Edit :

A related result :

Let :

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(x+1\right)^{3}\left(1-x\right)-x-\frac{5}{4}$$

Then :

$$f\left(e^{-1}\right)<0\quad (1)$$

And :

$$f\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2}\right)=0\quad(2)$$

Edit after the comment :

We have from $(1)$ and $(2)$ (the extrema is also a root) :

$$\left(1+e^{-1}\right)^{3}\cdot\left(1-e^{-1}\right)<e^{-1}+1.25$$

Now using :

Let :

$$I_n(x)=e^x-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x^i}{i!}$$

Then we have as $|x|\leq 1$ :

$$|I_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{2}{n+1}\right)$$

And using again the Binet's formula the result follows .

---

---

Last edit :
An inequality for the fun !

$$\left(1-\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2e-2}\right)\cdot e^{-1}+\left(\frac{1}{2e-2}+1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2}\right)\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2}\right)^{e}\left(1+e^{-1}\right)^{\left(3-e\right)}-\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}{2}<0$$

---

---

---

Question :

How to show it by hand ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to show that last equation (if it's true). Just plug that number into the formula for $f$, multiply everything out, see whether you get zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you make a answer to clarify it ?Thanks!

Comment: I think you've already answered how to do it by hand, of course the result is not unique, check the error in computing $\cos(\sqrt{2}e^{-2})-\cos(\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\pi})-\varphi$

Comment: What part needs clarifying, Erik? You have a number, $(\sqrt3-1)/2$. You have a formula, $f(x)=(x+1)^3(1-x)-x-(5/4)$. Wherever you see $x$ in the formula, you replace it with the number. So, for example, $x+1$ becomes $((\sqrt3-1)/2)+1$, which simplifies to $(\sqrt3+1)/2$. And $(x+1)^3$ then becomes $((\sqrt3+1)/2)^3$. If you've done enough mathematics to be familiar with $e$, then surely you've done enough mathematics to be able to multiply out that 3rd power. So, just do all the arithmetic of substituting in and multiplying out, and see whether or not you get zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hum you're totally right I add it ! Thanks !