# Find all the functions $f(x)$ defined by a quartic and some contraints

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots

Well It's a follow of one question of mine [Approximation of the golden ratio using exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263234/approximation-of-the-golden-ratio-using-exponential)

Let $-2\leq x\leq 2$ then define  :

$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=f(x)\leq0$$
Where $a,b,c,d,e\in R$

Then find all the function $f(x)$ such that :

1.Denotes by $r_i$,$1\leq i\leq 4$ the four real roots of $f(x)$ such that :$$r_1=r_3\leq 0,\quad r_2=r_4\geq 0,\quad,r_1=-1-r_2$$

2.The roots $r_1,r_2$ are such that :
$$f'(r_1)=f'(r_2)=0$$

I can exhibit a such polynomial wich is :

$$g\left(x\right)=a(\left(x+1\right)^{3}\left(1-x\right)-x-\frac{5}{4})$$

where $a>0$

I have tried also a linear substitution on $g(x)$ without attain the goal .

Maybe we need to play with [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) .

Question :

How to find all the $f(x)$ or equivalently the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ ?

Thanks in advance for your effort and don't forget to have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. $\;r_1=r_3\leq 0,\quad r_2=r_4\geq 0,\quad,r_1=-1-r_2$

This is equivalent to $r_1+r_2=-1$ and $r_1\,r_2 \le 0$.

> 2. $\;f'(r_1)=f'(r_2)=0$

This is redundant, since the derivative will always be zero at a double root.

The monic quadratic with two real roots with opposite signs that add to $-1$ is $x^2+x-b$ with $b \ge 0$. Squaring and scaling it gives the general quartic that satisfies the given conditions:

$$
f(x) = a\left(x^2+x-b\right)^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;a \ne 0,\;b \ge 0 \tag{1}
$$

If the condition is added that $\,f(x) \le 0\,$ on $\,[-2,2]\,$ then the additional restriction is $\,a \lt 0\,$.

> I can exhibit a such polynomial wich is : $\;g\left(x\right)=a\left(\left(x+1\right)^{3}\left(1-x\right)-x-\frac{5}{4}\right)$

This can be written in form $(1)$ as $\,g(x)=-\left(x^2+x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\,$.

Comment: Well it's very simple so far from my idea of the problem...I cannot cannot accept thanks !:-)

Comment: Hum a last question: is it the same story for $deg\geq 5$?

Comment: @ErikSatie Yes, assuming $f(x)$ is a polynomial, the conditions require it to have a factor of form $(1)$. For higher degrees, you can replace the constant $a$ with an arbitrary  polynomial $a(x)$ as long as $a(x) \le 0$ on the interval of interest.

Comment: Thanks great mind !

Answer (score 1):

If we write teh quartic as
$$f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$$ with (ignoring for the time being the inequalities)
$$r_1=r_3\qquad r_2=r_4\qquad r_1=-1-r_2$$
we have
$$f(x)=a(x-r_1)^2 (x+r_1+1)^2=a \big[x^2+x-r_1(1+r_1)\big]^2$$  Now, the given conditions imply $r_1 <0$ and $(1+r_1) <0$ that is to say $r_1(1+r_1)>0$.

As @dxiv already wrote, because of the double roots, the conditions for the derivative are redundant and, for any range, $a<0$.